# How to implement PPT Slides in react native script mobile app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am creating a react native mobile application for android & IOS. One of the feature is, that uploaded PPT's should be view-able in app (just like slideshare).

searched in google, no proper solution.Still working on different possibilities. 
Appreciate, any pointer to its implementation.

Comment: Give more detail please

Comment: Hi Seyha, 
We have a ppt and we want that ppt to be uploaded to out mobile app just like we have for slideshare. 

How should ppt slides should be visible on react native app page. 

We are now, using screen shots of ppts & uploaded as page for time being.